# Time taken for job based on IDs and group after query

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I'm using Oracle.
Having a table as:

```
Datetime                             Job_Indicator          JobID
17/02/2020 18:03:45                  Job start              Job 500
17/02/2020 18:15:55                  NA                     Job 500
17/02/2020 18:23:36                  NA                     Job 500
...
...
17/02/2020 18:30:22                  Job start             Job 600
17/02/2020 18:32:45                  NA                    Job 600
17/02/2020 18:40:12                  NA                    Job 600
```

I need to total time taken by each job. The operation would be:

For JobID “Job 500” -> Total Time Taken = 17/02/2020 18:23:36 - 17/02/2020 18:03:45

For JobID “Job 600” -> Total Time Taken = 17/02/2020 18:40:12 - 17/02/2020 18:30:22

The result should be:

```
JobID             Time Taken
Job 500           19 minutes 51 seconds
Job 600           9 minutes 50 seconds 
...    ...
```

I'm just not managing to get this query working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply subtract the start time (=min) and end time (=max) assuming the `datetime` column is a timestamp

```
select jobid, max(datetime) - min(datetime) as total_time_taken
from the_table
group by jobid;
```

The result of subtracting one `timestamp` from another is an `interval`

If the column is a `date`, you will get the duration in fractional days (e.g. 1.2 would be one day 4 hours and 48 minutes)

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation:

```
select jobID, max(datetime) - min(datetime)
from t
group by jobId;
```

This assumes -- as in your sample data -- that the minimum `datetime` is when the job starts.

This puts the results in decimal days.  I would recommend using decimal units.  If you want minutes:

```
select jobID,
       (max(datetime) - min(datetime)) * (24 * 60) as decimal_minutes
from t
group by jobId;
```